# Django can't find the files in static folder

Tags: python, html, django

I must be missing something.

So this should be how my folder does look:

[image]

Obviously with the asked image.

[image]

To increase portability, I use dynamic path in the code.

The code in `settings.py`

```
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango'
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),url(r'^rango/', views.about, name='about'))
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # Construct a dictionary to pass to the template engine as its context.
    # Note the key boldmessage is the same as {{ boldmessage }} in the template!
    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold font from the context"}

    # Return a rendered response to send to the client.
    # We make use of the shortcut function to make our lives easier.
    # Note that the first parameter is the template we wish to use.
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says: This is about page!<a href='../../'>Index</a>")
```

Note that the image is put on a html template. The html is ok (loaded), but the image dont.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %} <!-- New line -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rango says...</h1>
        hello world! <strong>{{ boldmessage }}</strong><br />
        <a href="/rango/about/">About</a><br />
        <img src="{% static "rango.png" %}" alt="Picture of Rango" /> <!-- New line -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Result?

[image]

The image got returned by a nasty `404`

Accessing from `127.0.0.1:8000/static/rango.png` or `manage.py findstatic rango.png` will result a failure.

However, accessing from `file:///D:/tango_with_django_project/static/rango.png` will be successful.

Thanks

Aditional information:

`DEBUG=TRUE`

I had checked `STATIC_PATH`, file did lead to the right path `D:\tango_with_django_project\static`

Is it possible due to backslash and forward slash, but if the slash is the problem, then the template should also broken.

Comment: Are you using Django's development server? Or serving the site using Nginx or Apache?

Comment: @rmcc I beleive Django's development server. You know, `manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 3):

In production static files should be served by the web server and not by django itself. That's why it is not enabled by default.

You need to say to the development server that it must serve the static files. I think that setting `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py` should be enough.

You may also need to add this in your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'your_app.views.home', name='home'),


    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)

if settings.DEBUG :
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
    )
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Is it ok with Debug set to true?

Comment: This is interesting. `settings.DEBUG` is `False`. So modify it by `settings.DEBUG= True`?

Comment: If I set `settings.DEBUG` to `True`, python can't reckon 'urlpatterns` and (possibly) 'patterns'. I believe some library must be imported?

Comment: you must set `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py`. I think it is enough for django 1.6 (but i am not sure). If it is not enough, you may have to add the `urlpatterns`stuff in your `urls.py`.

Comment: Hmm. Done job. Still same thing. I really sure this `urlpatterns` and `patterns` is the final problem. But I can't figure out how to "connect it". I try `from rango import urls` (where the `urlpatters` stuff originated), but still no luck. Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: The `urls.py` stuff should be in your project `urls.py`. I don't think you need anything more to import... but I don't see your projet and it is difficult to say

Comment: I think I shall ask follow up question, for the time being this is very good! Thanks =)

Comment: Add the:
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )

to  your urls file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may have to do with a lack of finders for the app's directory. Add the following to the project's setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```